# How to show multiple Access database columns in a WinForms ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a simple access database that has an "ITEM ID" and an "ITEM NAME". Below is an example.

1 Sword

2 Axe

3 Cat

When trying to get this into my listBox using a query it displays "System.Data.DataRow".
I have found ways to show the "ITEM ID" or "ITEM NAME" separately but not together as I desire.

If anyone could tell me how to make it show up "1 Sword" that would be great as I have been searching for answers for hours now.

```
private void RunQuery()
{
    errorMsg = "";
    q = SearchBoxItemsAll.Text;
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        a.SelectCommand = cmd;
        a.Fill(dt);
        a.Dispose();

        listBox1.DataSource = dt;
    catch (Exception ex)
    {}
}
```

Right now I am using a query box to call the above hoping to make it display the results onto the listBox.

Also I am using WinForms in visual studio 2015 (required). I also don't want to use anything other than a listBox. Apart from this issue it has the look I want and does everything I need.

Comment: what is the column name for "ITEM ID" and "ITEM NAME"? do this in your query ITEMID(columnname) + ' ' + ITEMNAME(columnname) AS ITEM

Comment: right now they are named ITEM ID and ITEM NAME in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void RunQuery()
{
    errorMsg = "";
    q = SearchBoxItemsAll.Text;
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        a.SelectCommand = cmd;
        a.Fill(dt);
        a.Dispose();
       foreach(var v in dt.Rows)
       {                        
         listBox1.Items.Add(v[0].ToString()+" "+v[1].ToString());
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {}
}
```

The better way to do it is by specifying DisplayMember and ValueMember and changing your SQL:

```
private void RunQuery()
{
    errorMsg = "";
    //q = SearchBoxItemsAll.Text;
    //Concatenate the ID and the Name in the SQL Query
    q = "SELECT [ITEM ID] , ([ITEM ID] +' '+ [ITEM NAME]) AS [ITEM NAME] FROM ITEMS";
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        a.SelectCommand = cmd;
        a.Fill(dt);
        a.Dispose();
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ITEM_NAME";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "ITEM_ID";
        listBox1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {}
}
```

Comment: I did try that, however it doesn't show the ITEM ID still when using 
SELECT * FROM ITEMS as the query only shows the ITEM NAME

Comment: change sql Code to 

`SELECT [ITEM ID]  , ([ITEM ID] +' '+  [ITEM NAME]) AS  [ITEM NAME] FROM ITEMS`

Comment: Got an error 'The provider could not determine the Double value. For example, the row was just created, the default for the Double column was not available and the consumer had not yet set a new Double value.'

Hang on ill look at your changes and see if it changes. EDIT: yeah still the same message

Comment: @YuriSuzumiya can I suggest you DONT use spaces in column names.And when you say `The provider could not determine the Double value` - why are you using a Double datatype, just use an Integer datatype for the Item_ID column

Comment: I am using an integer, i have no idea why it is complaining about a double

Comment: @Manu Varghese Any ideas?

Comment: Some reason this just didn't work with numbers for me so I changed the field to text which solved the issue in a kind of hacky way.

But other than that your answer worked so I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

ListBox control does not support multi column display. Try ListView Control instead and add subitems

Comment: I never wanted multi column display I wanted to show both in the 1 column which is now working.